# C#: Access a reverse enumerator for a linkedlist

Tags: c#, enumerator

I've created a "reverse itearator" for a LinkedList, now I would like to use it with an extension method:

```
public static class LinkedListExtensionMethods
{
    public static IEnumerator GetReverseEnumerator<T>(this LinkedList<T> linkedList)
    {
        return new LinkedListReverseEnumerator<T>(linkedList);
    }

    public static IEnumerator<T> GetReverseGenericEnumerator<T>(this LinkedList<T> linkedList)
    {
        return new LinkedListReverseEnumerator<T>(linkedList);
    }
}
```

However if I write:

```
foreach (ICommand command in _CompoundDoCollection.GetReverseEnumerator<ICommand>())
```

it doesn't work.

What should I do?

Comment: What does "It doesn't work" mean?  Does it throw an error, are the results not what you expected? Does it not compile? etc

Comment: Why a 'reverse' enumerator when you could just iterate backwards through a normal enumerator?

Comment: @Cos, how do you iterate backward through a normal enumerator?

Comment: @svick, see the answer I posted below..

Comment: @Cos, your solution has nothing to do with enumerator, i.e. `IEnumerator<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: @taylonr: it throws a compile error, saying that LinkedList.GetEnumerator() doesn't return an object that has a GetEnumerator method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not how foreach works.  Anything that implements the IEnumerable interface must override the GetEnumerator method.  This is the method called by foreach.  If you want to enumerate backwards, you need to make your own IEnumerable and have it's GetEnumerator return the ReverseEnumerator.  You can stil to this with a extension method, just have the extension method convert your LinkedList to a ReverseLinkedList.